# UIImageView changes its display size when added to a new window

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, uiimage, uiwindow

In the initial view, the UIImageView has a size of 60x60, and it holds a UIImage of size 300x300. It appears on screen as it should, at a size of 60x60.

However, when I do this:

```
[self.topWindow addSubview:theImageView];
```

The image view jumps to a display size of 300x300, the size of the UIImage it contains. Why does this happen? Both the initial window and the new window have the same size. Logging the frame of the image view after being added to the new window shows that the size is still 60x60. What could cause the UIImage to no longer respect the size of the UIImageView that contains it? Again, the only thing I'm doing is adding as a subview of a different window.

EDIT: I tried doing the same thing with a simple UIView. Its size does not change when added to the new window. Only happens with a UIImageView.

Comment: Have you check the image view's `clipsToBounds` property. It seems like the property was set to `NO` so the content of the image view could draw out of the view's rect.

Comment: setting clipsToBounds = YES has no effect. Tried some different content modes as well. No luck.

Comment: have you set an autoresizingmask on your imageview?

Comment: No. And in fact, if I just remove the view from its superview and then re-add it to the same superview, the same issue will occur.